# How can I have 2 create methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a business directory which as a businesses controller, featuring show and new pages. However, on each show page I need a contact form to contact the business. This contact form will require a create method itself to launch the email protocol.

I'm stuck however as I'm not sure how I can have 2 create methods in one controller.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have any number of forms on each page, each associated with a distinct controller. In your case, apart from the business controller, you could create a separate controller for the Contact form with its own set of actions.

Comment: Your method name need NOT be called `create`. You can call it something else. You just need to add a route for it

Comment: @Anand How would I have a separate controller while including its methods in another controllers views? Thanks.

Comment: Views are just html - each form can submit (post, put, ...) to a controller. For example, every web page has a search box, but also a main page, potentially with a form on it. Each of those could talk to independent controllers when you click the corresponding button,say. Or you could even group actions for such model-less forms into the home controller.

Comment: @Anand how would I define which controller a form_for helper is attached to?

Comment: There are several ways to do that - read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for a good overview of how you can create forms and specify controller/action/method, etc.

Comment: @Anand I have added this however it does not seem to be connecting with the controller properly. Check out the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066976/i-dont-get-why-this-platformatic-mail-form-contact-form-isnt-working

Answer (score 1):

Add this to route

```
match 'contact', to: 'businesses#contact', via: [:post]
```

or if you already have `resources :businesses`, you can add a collection route

```
resources :businesses do
  collections do
    post :contact
  end
end
```

And add an action to businesses controller

```
def contact
  ..
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I link this renamed create method to its relative renamed new method? as I can't have 2 new methods either

Comment: Also will I need to put the renamed "new" method in the resources as you did with the renamed create?

Comment: First, this is not a renamed method, it is an additional method along with `create`, To add a corresponding new method, add another route and action, say `get :new_contact` and  in controller `def new_contact .. end`