# I don't get why this platformatic mail form contact form isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

models/lead.rb

```
class Lead < MailForm::Base
  attribute :fullname

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "callumshorty@hotmail.com",
      :from => "admin@uk-franchise.co.uk"
    }
  end
end
```

controllers/lead_form_controller.rb

```
class LeadFormController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(params[:lead_form])
    @lead.request = request
    @lead.deliver
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :lead_form
```

views/listings/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @lead, :url => url_for(:controller => 'lead_form', :action => 'new') do |lead| %>
  <%= lead.text_field :fullname %>
  <%= lead.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The error when trying to access the show page:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

On line:

```
<%= form_for @lead, :url => url_for(:controller => 'lead_form', :action => 'new') do |lead| %>
```

Any help would be super appreciated, can't stand these mailers :(

Answer (score 0):

Your @lead needs to be initialised in the ListingsController#show action, since your lead form is in that view. Try adding `@lead = Lead.new` in the  ListingsController#show method.

Comment: Thanks mate, do you have any advice on how I can pass in the listings email to be the recipient of the mailer? struggling with it :(